code commit using git when multiple commits are there on the same jira
I have a feature branch and on that I have 2 commits. For example this is what I see when using the commmand
git log -2
I see below
commit abcd(HEAD-> features/<jiraId>,origin/features/<jiraId>)
Author: xyz
Date: 1/1/2024
 jira description

commit efgh
Author: xyz
Date:1/1/2024
 jira description

so jiraId is same here but description is different since both commit hash refers to different but related functionality (for example code cleanup/refactor) along with implementation of actual changes.
Now I want to make some code changes against efgh. How do I do it? Any suggestions. I am not familiar with Git commands and hence asking it

Can you clarify what you're asking? Do you want to throw away the latest commit and go back to efgh and make changes again?

Are you sure that both commits have HEAD-> features/<jiraId>,origin/features/<jiraId>?

corrected the output of "git log" command. Head is shown only for one. @ndc85430 I have some code changes specific to functionality change and some code changes for clean up. I want to commit the relevant code against specific messages

Is there a reason you can't just add new commits with the right changes and relevant messages?

You either do the changes & then git comit --fixup=efgh or do a an interactive rebase git rebase -i efgh^1.
